# How does division work in this case?

Tags: arithmetic

*I understood how division works for integers when I saw this [Khan Academy video](https://youtu.be/jTbIw2iR8WU). He elucidates it by the example $176÷8$. But I am unable to figure out how $1.76÷8$ works from the same standpoint.*

---

**My first thought**: I would evaluate $176÷8$ and then place a decimal after two digits from the right. I am not sure if that's an accurate justification. Could someone tell me how $1.76÷8$ works?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [tag:division-algebras] are part of abstract algebra.  [tag:arithmetic] would be a more appropriate tag for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The justification relies on the fact that $$(a ÷ b)÷ c = (a ÷c)÷b$$

If you have a cake, that you divide it in $3$ equal parts, and then you divide each part in $4$ equal subparts, you will get the same result as if you divide the cake in $4$ equal parts, then each part in $3$ equal subparts.

Here, with $a=176$, $b=100$ and $c=8$, you get that
$$1.76 ÷ 8 = (176 ÷ 8) ÷ 100$$

Comment: But how do you know $22÷100=0.22$ before knowing how to work with division and how does it work?

Comment: Hmm the question is not really to understand division, then. It is rather to understand how we represent numbers ! What does $0.22$ mean to you ? How do you define such a number as $0.22$ without knowing anything about division?

Comment: Division is not associative, you must understand that . Therefore your whole answer is wrong

Comment: @SAGNIKUPADHYAY Where did I say that division is associative ? Where did I use that ? Do you even know what associativity mean ?

Comment: Please prove that $22÷100=0.22$.

Comment: @NirajRaut Ok, but for it, you have to tell me what $0.22$ means.

Comment: @SAGNIKUPADHYAY Please remove your downvote. My answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe But for it, you have to prove me that $22 ÷ 100 = 0.22$.

Comment: Ok, so you don't know what $0.22$ means, but you are interested in proving a statement about $0.22$ ? In maths, we do the opposite order : we *define* objects, and then, we prove properties about them. You cannot prove anything about $0.22$ if you don't even know what it means.

Comment: @NirajRaut the decimal notation $0.22$ is defined as $(2\times10^{-1})+(2\times10^{-2})$. So basically the notation means divide $2$ into 10 parts and select one part. Next divide $2$ into 100 parts and select one part. Add those two parts together.

Comment: @Jamal Thanks. It makes sense :-) But how can we visually think about $22÷100$ *(on the same standpoint as mentioned in the video)*?

Comment: @NirajRaut So do you want to visualize it in terms of the quotient and the remainder of the result?

Comment: @Jamal Nope, in the decimal form *(the remainder should be zero)*

Comment: @NirajRaut The quotient and remainder of the result of division here can only be integers. So you can't force for some result to have 0 remainder.

Comment: @Jamal I was talking about visualizing $22/100$ by the same standpoint as described in the video?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112568/discussion-between-jamal-and-niraj-raut).

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you can see the result as a simple decomposition :

$$176÷8=100\times1.79÷8$$

which gives us

$$1.76÷8=\dfrac{1}{100}\times(176÷8)$$

Finally you just have to take the result of $176÷8$ and shift the point from two ranks to the left.

I hope it is ok for you.

Comment: You have a typo in the last equation.  The 9 should be a 6

Answer (score 0):

$1.76 / 8$ is just $(176 \cdot 10^{-2} )/ 8 = (176/8) \cdot 10^{-2}$. So, evaluate $176/8$ first, which gives $22$, and now you have to multiply by the remaining $10^{-2}$. Multiplying by $10^{-2}$ is essentially just moving the dot in $22.0$, $2$ times to the left, and hence we get that $1.76/8 = 0.22$.

Note that $10^{-2}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: Why $10^{-2}$ is equivalent to $1/100$?

Comment: $n^{-k} = \frac{1}{n^k}$ for $n \neq 0$. This is a rule in algebra. Therefore, we get that $10^{-2} = \frac{1}{10^2} = \frac{1}{100}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1.76 ÷ 8 = \frac{176}{100} ÷ 8$$
$$\implies 1.76 ÷ 8  = \frac{176}{100} × \frac{1}{8}$$
$$\implies 1.76 ÷ 8 = \frac{176}{100 × 8}$$
$$\implies 1.76 ÷ 8 = \frac{176}{8} × \frac{1}{100}$$
$$\implies 1.76 ÷ 8 = 22 × \frac{1}{100}$$
$$\implies 1.76 ÷ 8 = \frac{22}{100}$$
And now put the decimal point before the first 2 of 22 as the whole number is divided by 100. Therefore, your answer is $$0.22$$